# Efficient way to find array elements not in mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, meteor

Let say I have this array

```
const testItems = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
```

and a mongodb collection such as

```
const Cart = new Meteor.Collection('cart');
//{
//  _id: String,
//  items: [String]
//}
```

What could be an efficient way to check what elements of `testItems` are not in any record of any array `items` from that collection?

I naïve way would be to go by iteration

```
const missingItems = testItems.filter(item => !Cart.findOne({ 'items': item }));
```

But is there a way that would require less I/O?

Answer (score 0):

The solution would be the difference between the `testItems` set and the intersection of `testItems` and set of all entities in `items`.

To get the set of all entities inside an array, we can use [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) operation followed by a `$group`. For calculating the difference between sets, [$setDifference](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/) can be used.

```
Cart.aggregate([
{$unwind: '$items'},
{$group: {_id: '$items'}},
{$match: {_id: {$in: ['a', 'b', 'c']}}},
{$group: {_id: null, set: {$push: '$_id'}}},
{$project: {_id: 0, ans: {$setDifference: [['a', 'b', 'c'], '$set']}}}
])
```